# Unusual iMessage received from my mom, who wasn't aware she sent it

Tags: ios, messages

I received a iMessage via my mom's locked iPhone 4 while simultaneously calling her.  I stated I just received a message from you. She was confused because she doesn't use or know how to use this feature.

The content said "Can't talk now - On my way.".  I sent her a screenshot of this verbage to which I was referring to.  She allowed another family with more experience of iPhone to investigate.  They had no record or proof on their end of what I had sent but the rest of the message thread was identical.

How can I receive a random message seemingly via my mom's telephone number that she did not send?  Can we be part of someone else's spying on and unlocked phone?

I am extremely confused.  I called AT&T and Apple and neither could help me.

Answer (score 14):

Check the following:

1. Settings
2. Phone
3. Click the third line (free translated) "Answer with text message"
4. The **exact** text you received is right there.

If you have a running phone call, your screen will turn black once the sensor will notice the darkness of your face being close to it.

Once you click on your phone during an incoming call, you can decline the call and answer with one of the messages explained above.

This has nothing to do with spying and hacking.

Comment: I do this on my Android phone all the time. My wife will call me and I'll fumble around in my pocket getting my phone out only to realize I rejected her call with "I will contact you as soon as possible" or some other equally impersonal message. Free ticket to the dog house, for sure!

Answer (score 10):

You have received an automated response from your Mom's phone while you were calling her.

She must have inadvertently used 2 ups..ups when trying to answer your call rather than answering normally, and therefore accidentally used the "Respond with Text" function, which has a standard text of "Can't talk now - On my way".

There are other options to choose from, such as "I'll call you later" and "What's Up?" by default, or you can edit the defaults to read with your own message in `Settings > Phone > Respond with Text`.

That message is sent automatically via iMessage format if the recipient (i.e. the caller) is a valid iMessage address (otherwise as an SMS), and should show in her sent messages in iOS7.1, but I am not sure about earlier versions.